# How can I show lines in a textarea to make it look like notepad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show lines in my text-area to make it look a like notepad. I have a single text-area only. The below notepad is for reference.

[image]

Comment: .box{
background:#ffffff url(image.gif) no-repeat left;
text-align:center;

}
 Try this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an idea: http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/css-styling-textarea-give-notebook-notepad-look/

In short: set a `background-image` and set `line-height` to whatever line height the image is using.

Comment: You have to make sure to get the image exactly right, though. The examples others have posted break after a few lines. And the example you posted breaks as soon as there is a scrollbar.

Comment: Getting it not to break is definitely the challenge here. I have not tried this myself, but I would suspect that if you created an image 20px high, repeated that as a background-image and set the line-height to 20px as well it should align. I guess you would also want to stay away from too large `inline-block`s in the content, which might potentially shift the line-height a couple of pixels down.

Comment: The background also needs to move when scrolling, too. Otherwise you can scroll half a line and the text is over the lines, not the between the lines.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with CSS styling, based on your image, you can do this:

```
​textarea#area {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #fff url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfzKa.jpg") no-repeat -75px -160px
}​
```

See the example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/v3uyX/1/) here

Comment: Looks nicer if you can see the whole image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9289821/956397

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="text">some text</textarea>​
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfzKa.jpg);
    height: 664px;
    width: 495px;
    line-height: 29px;
    padding-top: 136px;
    padding-left: 120px;
}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ptpgb/4/

Comment: Why? Use a background image, that's what it's there for!

Comment: Downvote removed. Don't be scared of downvotes, think of them as constructive comments to help you improve. If your answer is not helpful/incorrect, you'll be downvoted and notified of it. That's why I always leave a comment when I downvote. Happy editing!

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) says "Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases". So I only use it if something is really wrong. Not for "working but ugly" cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one as well

```
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
 background: url(/source/notebook.png) repeat-y;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 font: normal 14px verdana;
 line-height: 25px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May be we both struck the link at same time. I first tried if its working and then posted here.

Comment: sure, I was not saying it with a bad intention, was just saying :).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a background image via CSS should work.

```
textarea{ background-image:url(notepad.png); color:ff0000; }
```

[look at here](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directtextareabgimage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check try

```
<textarea class="notepad"></textarea>

.notepad {
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynxjD.png) repeat-y;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 font: normal 14px verdana;
 line-height: 25px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FzFaq/1/