# Show page lines in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a HTML5 iPad application where I want to provide the user with a text area with a page lines like effect to enter their details. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create a simple PNG-image containing a horizontal line and use it as a repeating background on your textarea.

**I created a simple example**: http://jsfiddle.net/r4c2a/1/

Step by step, what you should do is:

1. Create a repeating pattern image.
2. Create your textarea.
3. Use CSS to define the line-height of the image and make it as high as your pattern is.
4. ???
5. Profit

Of course, this is just a rudimentary example and you can style it pretty much any way you want it to look.

Comment: Thanx a Lot Buddy. I saw this example and now I am able make this page.

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` for textarea?
Eg: http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-nice-textarea/

Answer (score 0):

This type of questions are already been answered at
[How can I show lines in a texarea to make it look like notepad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289761/how-can-i-show-lines-in-a-texarea-to-make-it-look-like-notepad)

And ::
[CSS Styling text areas like notebook-look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304436/css-styling-text-areas-like-notebook-look)

Please refer to them