# Jquery textarea growing with css style

Tags: jquery, autogrow

I need to make auto growing textarea. This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/EkpVn/1/

CSS:

```
#contact form textarea {
display: block;
margin: 16px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
color: #084a94;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 22px;
width: 345px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #122266;
resize: none;
height: 25px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('.message_autogrow').autogrow();
});
```

and the final look with autogrowing should look like this:

[image]

this is not working for me, how to do it right?

Comment: You did not include the library file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to properly include and use the [JQuery Autosize plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/), then call it on your element:

```
$(function() {
   $('.message_autogrow').autosize();
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EkpVn/3/)

Comment: thank you, but the I also have a problem with that border-bottom, he should expand in each new line, like in image, how to do that?

Comment: @baitas212123 [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289761/how-can-i-show-lines-in-a-texarea-to-make-it-look-like-notepad) has some good suggestions. I think you might also be able to do it with a pure CSS background if you don't want to use an image.

Comment: i need to do that with CSS but I don't think its doable with CSS (the background like mine)

Answer (score 1):

I added the library's code in the jsFiddle, and the method call is actually `autoGrow();` with upper case **G**.

```
$(function() {
   $('#message').autoGrow();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkpVn/2/