# How to show lines in a textarea with relative line-height?

Tags: html, css

Maybe somebody can help me with this problem: I'm looking for a javascript-free solution to show lines in a textarea. The [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289761/how-can-i-show-lines-in-a-texarea-to-make-it-look-like-notepad) does not work for me because it depends on a fixed line-height inside the box.
My textarea looks like this:

```
textarea{
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

so an image-only-solution does not work. Is there something, maybe CSS3-related, that could archive that?
I've tried

```
background: url('whitepx.png') repeat left 2em #363636;
```

but that colors the whole textarea white.

---

**UPDATE**

I think I got it. Sorry if I couldn't make my question clear enough.

This is my css finally:

```
textarea
    {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    resize: none;
    height: 58em;
    width: 530px;
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#363636, #363636 20%, #fff 22%);
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#363636, #363636 20%, #fff 22%);
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#363636, #363636 20%, #fff 22%);
    background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(#363636, #363636 20%, #fff 22%);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#363636, #363636 20%, #fff 22%);    
    background-size: 100% 2em;
    background-attachment: local;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://cssdesk.com/rVjt8). Looks good enough to me.

Comment: what do you mean by show lines? you mean to highlight a line in a text area?

Comment: make a fiddle, maybe?

Comment: I mean to show notepad-like lines inside the textarea, like in the picture of the linked question.

Comment: Then what's the matter in using the image?

Comment: The matter is I cannot create an image with 2em height.

Comment: can you provide jsFidle along with image `whitepx.png`

Answer (score 0):

You can achive by this way

try to give using multiple line  `box-shadow`

check > http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/09/css3-spread-value-and-box-shadow-on-one-side-only/

Comment: sorry if I didn't described my problem exactly enough, but that isn't what I was looking for. See my updated question for a solution that seems to work.